# Best way to open, and write (save) content in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, midas-editor

I would like to know the best method to open an html file to an iframe that has document.designMode="on" functionality, and then save any edits to this html file (essentially an open and save method for the Mozilla Midas spec)

I only would like to use javascript or PHP

[moz midas spec](https://www.mozilla.org/editor/midas-spec.html)

I am very new to javascript so please excuse me if this is relatively easy.
thanks